# Troubleshooting a ridiculously simple WebApi in VS Code on NET.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have a working webpage (front-end strictly) and I was curious of I could add a WebApi without leaving VS Code. So I created a directory called *webapi* in the root of my project and added a file *demo.cs* containing the following.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace WebApi
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class Demo : Controller
  {
    [HttpGet] public string Ping() { return "yo!"; }
  }
}
```

After some googlearching for references, I made sure that my *project.json* contains the following.

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.1",
```

I also edited the configuration methods like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvcCore();
  services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
  IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  loggerFactory.AddConsole();

  if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

  app.UseMvc();
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseFileServer(true);
  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

Now, as I execute the project with *dotnet run*, I get no errors, the page functions but I can't seem to access the text I meant to expose. The extra problem's that I'm not sure if I've got the WebApi running but using the wrong URL (I went *localhost:port* with */api/donkey*) or if it's not running at all.

How can I verify that it's up? What would be the address? Is there something else I'm missing in the setup?

The guides tell partially different things, which I guess depends on the rapid evolution of NET.Core. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: based on the attribute routes it would map to `GET http://localhost:port/api/demo`

Comment: @Nkosi All right, we're getting somewhere. So, I'm getting 404 on that address. Meaning, it's not running or not routing properly. Suggestions on troubleshooting?

Comment: Checking. but in the mean time look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using documentation from

[Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

> To make attribute routing less repetitive, route attributes on the
>   controller are combined with route attributes on the individual
>   actions. Any route templates defined on the controller are prepended
>   to route templates on the actions. Placing a route attribute on the
>   controller makes all actions in the controller use attribute routing.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace WebApi {    
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class Demo : Controller {    
        [HttpGet] // Matches 'GET /api/Demo'
        public string Ping() { 
            return "yo!"; 
        }
    }
}
```

the start up should have this in the configure services

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    //...other code
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I've added *routes => { routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); }* to *app.UseMvc(...)* and it seems to trigger something. Now I get the error that *C:\...\webapi\demo.cs(6,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Controller' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*. I do have the reference in *using* section.

Comment: You have attribute routing on the controller and are already calling `app.UseMvc` which registers attribute routes by default. As for the error you are probably missing a `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` in the cs file

Comment: Apparently I can't implement *Controller*. I used *ControllerBase*. Now it compiles and starts but I still get no hit on the address. I commented out the route attribute, as you suggested.

Comment: No I was saying to use the attribute routing. not to comment it out. I was saying that you didnt really need `routes` delegate you added

Comment: You weren't kidding that documentation is all over the place. wow

Comment: Any idea on the *Controller* interface? I get a red squiggly with it. I needed to go with *ControllerBase* and I'm not sure if it was so smart? :)

Comment: I'm reading up on that now but it looks like you are missing a reference. I trying to see which one.

Comment: Found it! I'm so PO'd so I almost cry. I have *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.1"* but for the *Controller* class to be present I also need *"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1"*! Why on Earth?!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Everything else should work as it looks like you have the setup and attribute routes configured properly